# What is this Call of Cthulhu scenario set in England or Scotland, where a a dilettante asks the characters to look for his missing daughter?

Tags: published-adventures, product-identification, call-of-cthulhu

Around a month ago, I've read somewhere about a scenario, which right now I can't seem to find.

All I remember, that it's setting was either in England or in Scotland, and it has two key antagonists. If I am not mistaken, the hook is that a dilettante asks us to investigate his missing daughter, but that's not 100% info, maybe I am mixing things up already in my head. The other things I know about it are:

> that at the beginning of the scenario, one of the antagonists I think is starting to turn into a were-jaguar and kills a prostitute in the town, and at the end of the scenario if the players don't succeed the whole town is devoured by something.

I would be really grateful if anyone could point me to the name or the book of this scenario:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it, it is ["The Smoking Mirror"](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/214191/The-Smoking-Mirror), written by Simon Todd!

I happened upon it while browsing this [this list of CoC scenarios on YSDC CthulhuWiki](https://www.yog-sothoth.com/wiki/index.php/CoC:Scenarios) (a *very* useful resource) and seeing the adventure "The Smokestack Horror" (from [*Halloween Horror 2*](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/82010/Halloween-Horror-2)), from which the name of the adventure I was looking for just popped into my mind.

I still don't know where did I read about the premise of the scenario, but [here's a nice review of the adventure](http://rlyehreviews.blogspot.com/2017/08/smoke-mirrors.html) that I found after the name came back to me!

Comment: As a matter of completion if nothing else you could give an insight into how you found it, why it is the correct might be excess, but you could also mark this answer as accepted so that it is clearer the question has been answered.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Unfortunately, I can only accept my own answer after two days. As for the other part, I've edited my answer:)

Comment: The answer would also be improved by pointing out how/whether it matches the description you gave in the question (e.g. what aspects of the scenario match up to how you described it in the original post). Doesn't have to be a totally line-by-line breakdown from the question, but pointing out how the details match up would be nice. (See the second paragraph in Peregrin Took's answer for a basic example.) It also helps to know whether you were misremembering some of the details, or confusing that adventure with a different one.

Comment: The review suggests you misremembered the gender of the missing character, at least: "Just as the British Museum has taken delivery of a consignment of artefacts from a newly discovered city in Honduras, one of its employees from the Department of the Americas goes missing. Tristam Soames is a specialist in hieroglyphics and his father, Lord Soames, is worried enough to hire the investigators rather than the police." It is "set in England’s West Country" in the 1920s, though.